# interlocutor OR collocutor: what's the difference?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between **interlocutor** and **collocutor**?

I can't put my finger on the difference.

WEBSTER

> 1. Collocutor: a person to or with whom one speaks
> 2. Interlocutor: one who takes part in dialogue or conversation.

Comment: I suppose you searched in several dictionaries before posting. Can you please say IN the question (not in the comments) what you found out?

Comment: You might search a while before you find ***collocutor*** in any online dictionaries anyway. But it's not obvious to me there's any difference in the *meaning* - the difference is that [the shorter form doesn't and never did have any significant currency.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collocutor%2Cinterlocutor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) But somewhat surprisingly, the full OED doesn't flag it up as "rare".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - someone on the Using English forum: _I had not heard the word_ [collocutor] _before I became an UCLES examiner._

Comment: It may be worth noting that both are highly formal, and rather rare.  Interlocutor is a word which I'm vaguely familiar with, but don't think I'd ever actually use. I don't know the word "collocutor".  Have you actually seen this word in use outside of dictionaries?  The internet suggests nearly all use of the word is in reference to a jazz musician, Though the philosopher Jeremy Bentham did use it, in 1843.

Comment: [*Interlocutor* is a rare word, and it is still about 500 times as common as *collocutor*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interlocutor%2C%28collocutor*500%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Google tells me there are  84 instances of the plural **interlocutors** on ELU and 339 for the singular form. I imagine a few of them might be from me over the years, but I'm actually usually more likely to use **conversants**. Which is *far* less common, and more than once I've been asked what it means - maybe on ELL, maybe ELU, I don't recall. But I'd expect the average *ELU* user to be able to figure out **conversant** without a dictionary, in any context where I might have used it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - won't a number of people think of the adjective meaning of conversant - to be familiar with, and have knowledge or experience of the facts or rules of something?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Context nearly always makes it obvious whether a word is being used as a noun or an adjective. And actually, when I did my site-specific search above, I looked first for the *plural* form in both cases because I (wrongly) assumed most usages for ***interlocutors / conversants*** would be plural. Besides which, I myself would almost never have actually used adjectival ***conversant*** in my life! I use terms like ***know all about, am familiar with, am aware of*** - it's just that there aren't any really good alternatives to ***interlocutors, conversants***.

Comment: ...actually, I've just returned from my (to me, *early*) morning constitutional walk round the block, during which I continued to muse over the (to me, *surprising*) fact that ***conversants*** is "far less common" than ***interlocutors***. I only discovered that *while* posting my "84 instances" comment, but there wasn't room in the comment for a link to the NGram that proved it. And it was pure blind chance that the ***plural*** search term ***interlocutors*** was still in my clipboard, so the NGram compared the plural forms. I'd never have thought of the adjective if I'd searched singular!

Comment: ...the [***plural*** comparison chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conversants%2Cinterlocutors&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) looks ***very*** different to [the singular chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conversant%2Cinterlocutor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) even allowing for many instances of ***conversant*** being adjectival.

Comment: As an aside, Mr Interlocutor is the title of one member of a group of American (?) entertainers (Clowns?). He performs a similar function to the White Faced Clown in European tradition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same difference as between "hockey player" and "teammate". Both refer to a player on a team, but one of them is only meaningful in reference to some other player.

While it's fine to say Connor McDavid is a hockey player, it makes no sense to say Connor McDavid is a teammate. A teammate to whom?

Same with "interlocutor" and "collocutor". The first is a person who is participating in a conversation. The other is someone participating in a conversation *with someone in particular*.

> Good: My collocutor this evening is Sam Harris.
> Good: Sam Harris is a prolific podcast interlocutor.
> Bad: Sam Harris is a prolific podcast collocutor. *(whose collocutor?)*

Comment: OK. But every collocutor is an interlocutor.

Comment: @user1425 Sure, and every hockey teammate is a hockey player.

Comment: A hockey teammate is an interlocutor. A hockey player is a collocutor. To correspond with my statement, yours should have been as follows "Every hockey player is  a hockey teammate".  I don't know if it's important but it's a curious point.

Comment: @user1425 No, hockey teammate is not an interlocutor. Teammate corresponds with collocutor. Player corresponds with interlocutor.

Comment: Why? The other is someone participating in a conversation with someone in particular. It should be collocutor.

Comment: A teammate is someone who is on a team with someone in particular, just like a collocutor is someone in conversation with someone in particular. Interlocutors and hockey players are just people doing what they do.

Answer (score 3):

"Interlocutor" is a rare word.  It isn't used to to refer to someone you were having an informal chat with, it is restricted to formal contexts.  For example you might write in an essay

> Plato presents Socrates' interactions with his interlocutors as occurring spontaneously.

But it would be ridiculous to say

> Who was your interlocutor in the pub on Friday night?

(You'd just say "Who were you talking to?")

So "interlocutor" is a very rare word.

And "collocutor" is a couple of orders of magnitude more rare.  I can find 1 modern example outside of dictionaries, formal texts on linguistics, and obscure publications by non-native speakers:

> The first collocutor generally confined himself to asking questions on related practical and philosophical topics, while the second collocutor, Tatishchev's alter ego, offered considered opinions in response.

In this single example, its meaning seems identical to "interlocutor".

So in conclusion.  In speech and most writing, avoid both terms.  In formal essays, you can use "interlocutor".  Don't use "collocutor" at all.

Comment: The French counterpart of interlocutor is "interlocuteur", that is a common word for French speakers. When [translated to English](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=interlocuteur), there is a minority of occurrences where the word "interlocutor" is used. It confirms that the English word is rare and should probably be avoided.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember where I learnt the word now, in one of the Asterix comics.  Spoken by a Roman who was acting smug and superior.

Answer (score 0):

In Cambridge English speaking exams, the **[interlocutor](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/images/26841-cae-how-speaking-is-assessed.pdf)** is the title of the speaking examiner who speaks directly to the candidates.

Whereas the *assessor* is the second speaking examiner who sits quietly and assesses (marks) the candidates' performances.

I know this because I am a trained Cambridge examiner.  So the term *interlocutor* is very familiar for anyone who is particularly involved in Cambridge exams and as speaking examiners we use the term constantly.

Conversely, I have never heard nor read the term collocutor until this question was posted. Personally, I feel that both terms are rather [snooty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snooty)-sounding, the latter even more so  and I only use the word, *interlocutor*, for work.